# Get employees from a manager which is from another period

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a employee table like

```
Employee ID
Name
```

EmployeeManager table like

```
employeeid
employeeManagerid
intyear
intperiod
```

So every manager is an employee, employeemanagerid is the forigen key from employee table and it is an employeeid from the employee table

An employee can have multiple managers in a year that is the reason for 
intYear and intPeriod, intPeriod is the month so it will have value from 1-12

What i am trying to achieve is if a manager is selected in one period(months) and no manager is assigned for next three periods(months) then the same manager 
will be assigned to that guy,

to give an example

```
employee table
----------------------------------------------------------------
employeeid   name
1              a
2              b
3              c
4              d
5              e
-------------------------------------------------------------------

EmployeeManager table
----------------------------------------------------------------------
employeeid           employeemanagerid       intyear         intperiod
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1                           5                   2017            3
1                           4                   2017            4
2                           4                   2017            6
3                           4                   2017            6
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My query

```
select e.name,e.employeeid
from employee e
left join employeemanager em
on e.employeeid = em.employeeid
where
em.employeemanagerid  = @managerid
and em.intyear = @intyear
and em.intperiod <= @intperiod

the values supplied as a parameter are
@managerid = 4
@intyear = 6
@intperiod = 2017
```

What i want as expected result is

```
------------------------------------------------------
name               employeeid               
a                   1
b                   2
c                   3  
------------------------------
```

Employee b,c is straight match  but a has the manger set in period 4 which 
is still continueing till period 6

what i should change in the query to get this result
the parameter values are sent from c#.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are filtering out all records that are not for a specific manager, but you still expect those records to affect the results. You are also not doing anything to stop duplicates, if you had an employee go from manager 4 to 5 to 4 it would show twice. You need to get a query first that figures out who the correct manager is for each row for the period wanted, then do your main query from that first query. One way to do this is:

```
--This gets all manager records for the period (or before), with a rowno added 
--sorted so that the most recent manager is always number 1
With emData as 
(
    Select employeeid, employeeManagerid, intyear, intperiod
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by employeeid ORDER BY intyear DESC, intperiod DESC) as RowNo
    from employeemanager
    where intyear <= @intyear 
        and intperiod <=@intperiod
)
--This is your original query, changed to use the above as the source
select e.name,e.employeeid
from employee e inner join 
emData em on e.employeeid = em.employeeid
where
em.employeemanagerid  = @managerid
and em.RowNo = 1  --THIS MAKES SURE YOU ARE ONLY LOOKING AT THE MOST RECENT MANAGER
```